# Unity: Built In Scrollable Containers?

Tags: unity, ngui, gui

Is there a way to get a scrollable container in Unity without purchasing a plugin such as NGUI or TK2D?

I want to create a scrollable container of interactive elements that can be clicked on individually and be scrolled horizontally by the user dragging their finger. You can kind of think of this as something similar to the shop menus in Clash of Clans. Here's a quick mock that I made to demonstrate the behavior I'm looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOJSMDPdFUQ

Is there a built in way to do this in Unity without the need of purchasing an extra plugin such as NGUI or TK2D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Unity has this functionality built in. Both the [legacy GUI](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.BeginScrollView.html) system and the new [GUI system](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-scroll-rect) have scollable containers. Depending on how you show the containers, they can both achieve the functionality you're after.

Comment: Awesome! Do you know of a reference that demonstrates how to do this with the built-in system? I've Googled around for "scrollable container unity", "draggable container unity" without any luck.

Comment: Just what I'd search for on Google. This isn't really the place for asking for tutorials. I'd suggest using the newer system as it'll be far more "plug and play" than the older system. You'd want to modify your search to use 'UI SCROLL RECT' instead, since it's not called either of the things you mention.